# List file names of other excel files in a sub folder

Tags: excel, vba, csv, directory, path

I'm creating a spreadsheet with scripts that will run and take information from other csv files as dependancies. I've created a simple folder structure:

1. /main  *My spreadsheet is sat here
2. /main/Raw Reports  *raw csv files are stored here
3. /main/Completed Reports  *spreadsheets created when script is ran

It's my intention to list the file names in /Raw Reports to determine if all required csv files are in there before proceeding.

I've been trying to just use a shorter file path too, because I intend to share the folder that will be zipped and passed around the office, I can't stick to a static file/folder path. I was hoping to achieve something like adding a wildcard before and after the current directory, that way no matter where the folder is stored under desktop or documents, the code can still run.

Here's my attempts:

```
Sub FileNames()

Dim FolderName As String
Dim FileName As String

MsgBox ThisWorkbook.FullName
MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Path

'works
FolderName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "/Raw Reports/"

'doesnt work - bad file name or number
FileName = Dir(FolderName & "/*")

Do While FileName <> ""
    MsgBox FileName
    FileName = Dir()
Loop

End Sub
```

- 

```
Sub FileNames2()
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim i As Integer

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'doesnt work - path not found
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(ActiveWorkbook.Path)

For Each objFile In objFolder.Files

    MsgBox objFile.Name
    MsgBox objFile.Path
    
Next objFile
End Sub
```

- 

```
Sub FileNames3()

Dim FilePath, FileOnly, PathOnly As String

FilePath = ThisWorkbook.FullName
FileOnly = ThisWorkbook.Name
PathOnly = Left(FilePath, Len(FilePath) - Len(FileOnly))

SubFolder = PathOnly & "Raw Reports/"

'doesn't work - bad file name or number
FileName = Dir(SubFolder & "*")

Do While FileName <> ""
    MsgBox FileName
    FileName = Dir()
Loop

End Sub
```

I'm getting errors like *bad file name or number*, I can print the current path fine, but when I start adding wild cards and trying to move down a folder it errors out. It is worth mentioning that our office uses sharepoint and onedrive, so the file path that is printed is a https:// link, not C:something something something. Which is why I need dynamic links.

Comment: Try using `FileName = Dir(FolderName & "*.csv")`. In your first attempt...

Comment: Still not working, I tried that and also msgbox'd it to check the file path was correct and I'm still getting *bad file name or number* :(

Comment: Your `FolderName` ends with a `/` and your FileName then appends another `/` before the `*`. You don't need both.

Comment: It looks that you use slashes instead of backslashes (supposing that your OS is Windows)... Try `FolderName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Raw Reports\"`. Are you working in Windows or MAC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe the normal filesystem object can handle http sources.

If you can open up the sharepoint location in Windows explorer first you can then use the link you see in the Explorer bar in your code.

See this discussion for more details/
https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/loop-through-a-sharepoint-folder-and-open-in-excel.1176257/

Comment: Thanks, that pointed me in the right direction, I was able to make a work around:

path1 = Environ$("userprofile") & "\OneDrive - [onedrive name]\Desktop\Reports\"

MsgBox path1